# Play streamed audio from websockets JS

Tags: javascript, streaming

So I am making a Phoenix/Elixir backend server and want to stream audio from a user. I first thought about using WebRTC but as it is a p2p technology, I'll have a problem when a lot of users join. So I in the end, I thought that I could just transfer my data through a websocket to my server (which I am already using) and then broadcast the payload to all other users.

This is my current JS:

```
import channel from "./socket"

const constraints = window.constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: false
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  const audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
  console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
  console.log('Using audio device: ' + audioTracks[0].label);
  stream.oninactive = function() {
    console.log('Stream ended');
  };
  window.stream = stream; // make variable available to browser console

  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {

    const blob = event.data

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
    channel.push("audio:message:send", reader.result); // This way I properly get the base64 string
  };

   reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }

  recorder.start(1000);
}

channel.on("audio:message:recieve", payload => {
    let snd = new Audio(payload.message);
    snd.play();
})

function handleError(error) {
  console.log('navigator.MediaDevices.getUserMedia error: ', error.message, error.name);
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
```

With this, I am able to record one second and play it back on multiple devices at the same time only once. But I can't seem to edit the source after that. It is edited once but when I try to edit it again and play it I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Note that I am using base64 only for now as it's easier to see the data this was and I plan to change to raw binary values once I manage to get this up and running.

Also another note that I am a beginner at JS and take it easy on me if I did anything wrong!

**Edit:**

Okay so I just learned of the JS "promise" syntax and started using it:

```
var promise = snd.play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(_ => {
        // Well everything worked
    })
    .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    });
}
```

And I still get the same DOM exception with the same behavior (plays only once and that's it):

```
DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```